# Tree / shrub identification, grows in Ireland

Tags: identification

Can anyone identify this plant? It grows in Ireland. Picture taken in October so it is somewhat hardy (was about -1 at night recently). Looks a bit like Bay Leaf tree but no smell.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Pittosporum tenuifolium, though I'm not sure which variety it is. It's an evergreen small tree or large shrub, originating in New Zealand, and there are various cultivars with variegated or dark purplish brown leaves. It is not bone hardy - listed as H4 with the RHS, but survives winter temperatures a low as -10 deg C for short periods, so in an average winter, hardiness is not a problem in the UK and Ireland. Details here, though the image shown is not the variety you show in your photo, which I suspect might be P. tenuifolium 'Golden King' https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/13202/pittosporum-tenuifolium/details